# Cumulative product of user input floating-point values

Tags: c, recursion

I apologize if this appears as homework, but I am struggling to understand recursion in C.

Im trying to solve a problem where I must determine the cumulative product of n floating-point numbers, and I must read in a new number into the computer during each call of the recursive function. (Problem 7.49d of Schaums Outline of Theory and Problems of Programming with C)
I interpreted this to mean, each time the recursive function is called, the user has to enter a new value, and this value is multiplied with the previous value.

`p = (f1 * f2 * f3 * ... * ft)`

I finally was able cobble this solution together:

`

```
#include <stdio.h>

float product(int n);   /* function prototype */

int main()
{
    printf("This program returns the culmulative product of\n"
            "each number entered into the computer.\n");
    int n;
    printf("Enter how many numbers (n): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("culmulative product >> %2.2f", product(n));

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

float product(int n)
/* this function multiplies each number entered, recursively. */
{
    float sum = 1.0; float number;
    if(n > 0)
    {
        printf("number = ");
        scanf(" %f", &number);
        sum = sum * number;
        printf("sum > %f\n", sum);
        number = product(n - 1);
        return(sum * number);
    }
}`
```

But I am still struggling to understand what is happening in each recursive step, and why I had to `number = product(n - 1)` and `return (sum * number);`

Can someone please help explain it to me?

Comment: Sina, Hint: `if(n > 0)` is not true, what is the return value?

Comment: Hint also, try stepping through the code with `n = 1` and `n = 2` examples.

Comment: Tip: save time and enable all warnings.  I'd expect something like "warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]".

Comment: <crying emoji> <crying emoji>